# Moving Variance with Aggregation

Tags: r, time-series, aggregation, zoo

I have some 6 minute frequency thermocouple data. Thermocouples are installed at various heights and at each height there are a number thermocouple distinguished by radial position

```
DT_TI_RECORDED      HEIGHT      POS             TEMPERATURE
2018-05-16 00:00:00     1       90              111
2018-05-16 00:00:00     1       180             112
2018-05-16 00:00:00     1       270             113
2018-05-16 00:00:00     2       90              112
2018-05-16 00:00:00     2       180             114
2018-05-16 00:00:00     2       270             115
2018-05-16 00:00:00     3       90              112
2018-05-16 00:00:00     3       180             112
2018-05-16 00:00:00     3       270             113
...
2018-05-16 00:06:00     1       90              111
2018-05-16 00:06:00     1       180             112
2018-05-16 00:06:00     1       270             113
2018-05-16 00:06:00     2       90              112
2018-05-16 00:06:00     2       180             114
2018-05-16 00:06:00     2       270             112
2018-05-16 00:06:00     3       90              114
2018-05-16 00:06:00     3       180             112
2018-05-16 00:06:00     3       270             114
...
```

Every 6 minutes for each unique combination of height and position I would like to calculate a backwards *n* hourly moving variance Lets say 4 hourly.

The original code I am trying to duplicate is written for SAS stats package

```
    PROC EXPAND DATA=Raw_data
        OUT=Moving_Variance
        ALIGN = BEGINNING
    ;
    by HEIGHT POS;
    ID DT_TI_RECORDED ;
        CONVERT TEMPERATURE = Moving_4hour_Var /  METHOD = none TRANSFORMOUT = (MOVVAR 40); 
    #/* 40 obs at 6min freq = 4hour moving variance*/
    QUIT;
```

I have spent a couple of hours searching google I think the R library I need to use is called `zoo` and function I want is `rollapply` but I can't figure out how to combine aggregations with `rollapply`.

I have tried

```
moving_var <- Raw_data %>%
              aggregate(HEIGHT,POS) %>%
              rollapply( TEMPERATURE, width = 40, FUN = sd, fill = NA)
```

But does not work. I am very new to R programming and this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following aggregation:

```
library(zoo)

result = aggregate(temp ~ pos + height,
              data = df,
              FUN = function(x){
                  rollapply(x, width = 40, FUN = var, by = 40)
              }
)
```

`width` is the width of the rolling window, while `by` is how many points are skipped for the next window starting point. With 40 in each you'll get the start of each window next to the end of the previous one.

The resulting data frame has one column for each window. This structure can be considered as "wide". If you want to have it as a "long" format, use `gather` from tidyr or `melt` from reshape2.

Example:

```
df = structure(list(pos = c(0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 
                            180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 
                            0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 
                            270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 
                            180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 
                            0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 
                            270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 
                            180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 
                            0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 
                            270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 
                            180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 
                            0, 90, 180, 270), height = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), temp = 1:160), .Names = c("pos", 
                            "height", "temp"), row.names = c(NA, -160L), class = "data.frame")

> head(df,20)
   pos height temp
1    0      1    1
2   90      1    2
3  180      1    3
4  270      1    4
5    0      2    5
6   90      2    6
7  180      2    7
8  270      2    8
9    0      3    9
10  90      3   10
11 180      3   11
12 270      3   12
13   0      4   13
14  90      4   14
15 180      4   15
16 270      4   16
17   0      1   17
18  90      1   18
19 180      1   19
20 270      1   20


library(zoo)

result = aggregate(temp ~ pos + height,
              data = df,
              FUN = function(x){
                  rollapply(x, width = 3, FUN = var, by = 3)
              }
)
```

will result in:

```
   pos height temp.1 temp.2 temp.3
1    0      1    256    256    256
2   90      1    256    256    256
3  180      1    256    256    256
4  270      1    256    256    256
5    0      2    256    256    256
6   90      2    256    256    256
7  180      2    256    256    256
8  270      2    256    256    256
9    0      3    256    256    256
10  90      3    256    256    256
11 180      3    256    256    256
12 270      3    256    256    256
13   0      4    256    256    256
14  90      4    256    256    256
15 180      4    256    256    256
16 270      4    256    256    256
```

Comment: Thanks this is close to what I wanted. Is it possible to preserve the timestamps as well?, I do not want to skip any obs I.e every 6 mins I want to look back at prev 4 hours so I think I can just omit the by and should work.

Comment: Update trying your code I get:  Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: Another way you could try is to subset each combination of pos and height, one data frame for each. Then do a rollapply to the temperature column.